# What is "jquery-ui/ui/widget.js" for?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want to use jsdelivr to get a jQuery UI library. When I open the page:

https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/jquery-ui

It shows `/ui/widget.min.js` as the default file:

[image]

It's also the most requested file.

[image]

I found this widget file is much smaller than other jquery-ui library online. For example:

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js

This library with the same version `1.12.1` is of a much larger size.

What's the difference? Why jsdelivr is offering the `widget.js` as its default file? Is this because of a jsdelivr bug, or some reasons I haven't learned.

Comment: Note that you linked to the complete jquery-ui library. The widget code itself is much smaller size and only  747 lines when not minified https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/widget.js

Comment: What is this widget for? Is it playing a role like to load other parts of jquery-ui together?

Comment: All of [these](https://api.jqueryui.com/category/widgets/) have the same abstraction of the widget. You can learn more about it [here](https://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/widget-factory/)